# Unable to click on Xpath element even the correct path

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Unable to click on Xpath element even the correct path,tried with Webdriver wait and Javascript executor still no use.

My code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[text()='Next']")).click();
```

Page:

```html
<button id="paginationNext" class="btn pagination2__next" data-selenium="pagination-next-btn">Next</button>
```

Comment: My HTML page as below
<button id="paginationNext" class="btn pagination2__next" data-selenium="pagination-next-btn">Next</button>

Comment: Might I ask why you use an xpath when you can easily use the id attribute? Also, it would help to know what kind of error you get when you execute it.

Comment: I tried with Id also same issue then only trying with Xpath, actually the above one when i clicked it should go to next page,but now it's not clicking and no error
Tried the below method as well.
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[text()='Next']"));

   JavascriptExecutor js1 = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 

   js1.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", element); 
      element.click();

Comment: When i use id getting below error.
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <button id="pagination..." class="btn pagination2__next" data-selenium="pagination-next-btn">Next</button> is not clickable at point (1250, 689). Other element would receive the click: <div class="BackToTop--btn">...</div>
My code :
driver.findElement(By.id("paginationNext"));

Comment: Why xpath instead of id ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code is solved my problem..:)

```
   String pageCount = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='paginationPageCount']")).getText();
        String[] count = pageCount.split(" ");
        int s = Integer.valueOf(count[3]);
        int k =0;
            if(k < s){
                int attempts = 0;
                 while(attempts < 2) {
                        try {
                            Actions actions = new Actions(driver); 
                            actions.click(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Next']"))).build().perform();
                            break;
                        } catch(StaleElementReferenceException e) {
                        }
                        attempts++;
                    }
                WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10000);
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[text()='Next']")));
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Next']")).click(); 
            k++;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there are more than one element with the id "paginationNext". Try replacing the xpath with the css locator

```
css=button.pagination2_next
```

If this also does not work, please share a part of the HTML code to arrive at a xpath/css selector that would locate the element you're looking for precisely.

Comment: Thanks for response,but still no luck,the below is my HTML code to arrive to the button
<div class="clearfix pagination-panel" data-selenium="pagination-panel"><div id="paginationContainer" class="pagination2 clearfix" data-selenium="pagination"><span id="paginationPageCount" class="pagination2__text" data-selenium="pagination-text">Page 1 of 2</span><button id="paginationNext" class="btn pagination2__next" data-selenium="pagination-next-btn">Next</button></div></div>

Comment: Can you post a formatted version?

Answer (score 0):

You have a data-selenium attribute.  It would make the most sense to use that.

```
webDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//element[@data-selenium='pagination-next-btn']"));
```

Comment: Thanks for all responses,Problem is resolved using Actions and WebdriverWait